# Call jQuery function from ASP.NET code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have the following jquery function

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> 
>     $(document).ready(function() {
> 
>         $('#callGrowel').click(function() {
>             $.growlUI('Email Received', 'from Joe Bloggs');
>         });
>     });
> 
> </script>
```

and in my aspx page I have a div

```
<div id="callGrowel" >Run Growe l</div>
```

but I need a way of calling the growlUI jquery function from my code behind file in C# rather than clicking on a div in the UI.

Is this possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense really. Your C# code runs on the server to generate an HTML file which is passed to the client and translated there. jQuery can only operate on the HTML n the client side.

Is what you're trying to do not achieved by replacing

```
     $('#callGrowel').click(function() {
         $.growlUI('Email Received', 'from Joe Bloggs');
     });
```

with

```
     $.growlUI('Email Received', 'from Joe Bloggs');
```

?

Comment: No... I my C# code i am checking for updates to my email repository, and when I dedect a new email I want to fire the $.growlUI jquery function. I though if I attached it to a div or button element i could call in indirectly.

Comment: for example here you can call javascript from a code behind file http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/execute-javascript-function-from-aspnet.html

Comment: That link isn't really showing how to call javascript from C#, that's bad terminology on the author's part. What that is doing is injecting javascript into an HTML file. This is a dubious approach if you ask me. Better design: Load the basic HTML file, make jQuery.ajax() calls back to the server to find out if you've got any new emails and fire your growlUI method if the response says there is.

Comment: Ok... thanks for taking the time to post, I appriciate your help

Answer (score 4):

I've use following way and for me work 100% properly:

the first i create a function and write my jquery function in to the function in the my page:

```
<script>
function myFunction(params) {
    $.my_jquery(params...)
    ......
}
```

then i used this code in event handler of my control(for example click a button) who my control is inside a update panel:

```
protected void myButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .....
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction(params...);</script>", false);
}
```

successful

Comment: This solution is acceptable for ASP.NET FORMS projects with Page_Load methods on postback which I used successfully too. MVC and API inpage practice would be to do this dynamically in the Views/Controllers.