# Call jquery from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi i have a jquery function which executes when a button is clicked, i also need to execute this function from my code behind based on whether an Item has a comment attached to it. Here is the jquery

```
  //Comments Slide
$('.commentsnr').live("click", function () {
    // up to parent li
    $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $li.find("#commentload").slideToggle(300);
});
```

How do i call this from my code behind, thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call jQuery function from ASP.NET code behind C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397165/call-jquery-function-from-asp-net-code-behind-c)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this, but it will only be executed when the page is delivered or you receive a Postback.

See [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation.

```
string jquery = "$('.commentsnr').live(\"click\", function () {$li = $(this).closest('li');$li.find(\"#commentload\").slideToggle(300);});"

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key", 
             "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+ jquery +"</script>"
             );
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, i didnt use it in the end i forgot i could change the style attribute to show the div.                       cahrefReply.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(String), btnID,"$('.commentsnr').live("click", function () {
$li = $(this).closest('li');
$li.find("#commentload").slideToggle(300);});", True);
```

Comment: you can refer to  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ClientServer.aspx it may help

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but I'm guessing its just how to manually call this method..?

```
$(selector).click();
```

The problem you will have is that its not an ID, its a class. So in my example you'd have to update the selector to find the exact commentsnr that you want to 'click'