# I dont get redirected instead I get: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, redirect

I have a dialog which I need to commit so it disappear and then redirect else the redirect will happen inside the dialog.

I have this following method that do not work anymore:

```
private void CommitPopupAndRedirect(string url)
{
   var script = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>parent.window.location='{0}';window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>", url);
   Context.Response.Write(script);
   Context.Response.Flush();
   Context.Response.End();
}
```

I am recieving this exception my catch:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack.

What happens is the dialog disappear and then a refresh happens on the site, no redirect.

I have googled abit and I found

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

But it still didnt work.

Any kind of help is appreciated alot!

Comment: did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `RegisterStartupScript` for more information, please review:

[Call jQuery function from ASP.NET code behind C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397165/call-jquery-function-from-asp-net-code-behind-c-sharp)
or [Call jquery from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178811/call-jquery-from-code-behind)