# How to call Jquery function from C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to fadein and out a div after performing some code. This JQuery function is working fine when using the button's onclientclick property. But, Unable to call it from c#.

**JS:**

```
function Confirm()
{
 $(".saved").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
}
```

**C#:**

```
protected void btnsave_click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
  //some code
  upd.update();
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Confirm", 
   "<script type='text/javascript'>Confirm();</script>", true);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<asp:updatepanel id="upd" runat="server" updatemode="conditional">
 <triggers>
  <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="btnsave" eventname="click"/>
 </triggers>
 <contenttemplate>
  <div style="position:relative">
    <span class="saved">Record Saved</span>
    <asp:gridview....../>
  </div>
  <asp:button id="btnsave" runat="server" text="save" onclick="btnsave_click"/>
 </contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

**CSS:**

```
.saved
{
  position:absolute;
  background:green;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Have a look, it works with me https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859805/4074774

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C#

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "Confirm();", true);
}
```

#### JS:

```
<script>
   function Confirm()
   {
      $(".saved").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
   }
</script>
```

---

### Edit Improve Code

C#

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "Confirm();", true);
}
```

#### JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

       function Confirm() {
           $(".saved").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
       };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked only when the css visibility is 'visible'. I would like the span to stay hidden. On button's click, it should fade in and out.

Comment: Ok Figured that out...$(".saved").css("visibility","visible").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);

Answer (score 2):

When using asynchronous post backs is good to understand the events that you can actually handle on the client side (aspx file).

If you want to execute some client function (jquery, javascript) after an asynchronous post back has been made, I suggest using the `pageLoaded` event on the client side. So your javascript will be something like the following:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
    $(".saved").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
}
```

For more information please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx) MSDN page on the **Event Order for Common Scenarios** section.

Hope this helps

---

**Edit after comment to add filter example**

To filter logic in the `pageLoad` event depending on the element that raised the event, as stated in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx) MSDN page, on the **Animating Panels** section, you can do something like this:

```
var postbackElement;

function beginRequest(sender, args) {
    postbackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
}
function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
    if (typeof(postbackElement) === "undefined") {
        return;
    } 
    else if (postbackElement.id.toLowerCase().indexOf('btnsave') > -1) {
        $(".saved").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are other postback events too that do not require the span to fadein. How can I filter then.

Comment: There is an example for that in this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx , on the Animating Panel section... the main thing is to use the `beginRequest` event to store in a variable the element that is raising the postback and using that variable to filter the `pageLoad` event code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "Confirm();", true);
```