# Calling Javascript function from Code Behind in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript function in the External JS File. I want to call it from the co0de behind. How can I do that ?
I read somewhere that I can do from `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` but how, can anyone explain me.

JS File:

```
    Function1()
    {
      alert("came");
     //Some More logic
    }
```

**Update**

Calling from

```
//Tried this But NOT WORKING
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Function1", "Function1();", true);
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Function1", "Function1()", true);

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Jquery function from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216177/how-to-call-jquery-function-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I've often used this

```
string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');",alert);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

basically, it just inserts that line onto your page and runs it as soon as the page loads

Comment: define alert as what ever variable you want to see show in the alert

Comment: My Function1() is containing some big logic, which I want to reuse also.So I need to keep in the EXt JS FIle.

Comment: is Function1() in the code behind? It's a bit trickier to communicate from js-->c#. If that's the case it's easiest to use an ajax function from js

Comment: are you trying to pass your entire function to the page? that won't work

Comment: I am just trying to call the function, not pass it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"CallMyFunction","Function1();",true);
```

OR

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction",
                                     "Function1();",true);
```

another approach is

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "somekey", script, true);`

this will works during partial postbacks also.

Comment: @hellotemp11 try this.GetType() instead of this, GetType()

Comment: @hellotemp11 also try by putting an alert instead of function1() place and check is it working

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question you are looking for something like this:

```
//Following statement is used to call pre-defined javascript function
protected void btnServerSide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", true);            
}
```

[Here](http://www.webblogsforyou.com/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-code-behind-in-asp-net-c-vb-net/) is a site that provides some more details and examples

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863(v=vs.140).aspx) also has a great walkthrough with multiple examples

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.140).aspx) is my favorite of the walkthroughs listed above, it is very comprehensive

Comment: Probably because your trying to call javascript before it is even processed,  notice how mine fires off of a button click and you have yours within a prerender function

Answer (score 0):

sample code, which will include javascript file and then call method from the code behind.

**MyJSFile.js**

```
function Test() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs** -

```
 using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace CodeprojectTest
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            js.Attributes["src"] = "JScript1.js";
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(js);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "Test();", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the "script" and "myScript" should be same ? Why have you used those 2 variables here ?

Answer (score -1):

You may try this..

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "CallMyFunction", "myFunction()", true);
```