# How to post data to jQuery from ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I see lots of information about posting data from jQuery to an ASP.NET page using AJAX call, but nothing for the other way around.

How do I call a jQuery method from an ASP.NET page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Jquery function from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216177/how-to-call-jquery-function-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to call jquery from server side , here is an example for calling jquery from c#.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "postfunction();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ControllerName/FunctionName',
        data: '{mydate: "' + $("#mydata").val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);

            })
        }
    });
```